# Variable in selector jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, variables, select

I can't seem to get variables working within selectors in jQuery. This is a really simple but annoying bug! See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYzvL/) for an example:

The following does not work:

```
var folder_id = "folder";

$("#selects select[name='" + folder_id + "']").append('<span>Hi></span>');
```

Markup:

```
<div id="selects">
    <select name="folder_id">
        <option>hey</option>
    </select>

</div>​
```

Comment: Always include all of the relevant code **and** markup in the question itself, not just as a link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question I've added the markup from your fiddle for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question you actually asked (but see also below):

You're telling it to find a `select` with the `name` `folder`, not `folder_id`. But your `select` has the name `folder_id`.

So either change the code:

```
//                     v----- change here
var folder_id = "folder_id";

$("#selects select[name='" + folder_id + "']").append('<span>Hi></span>');
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYzvL/7/) (but again, see below under the break)

...***or*** change the markup:

```
<div id="selects">
    <select name="folder">
        <option>hey</option>
    </select>

</div>​
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYzvL/3/)

---

But note that you're trying to append a `span` to a `select`, which is invalid markup and won't work. [`select` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-select-element.html#the-select-element) cannot contain `spans` (only `option` and `optgroup` elements). If you meant to put it *after* the `select`, use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
//                                             v--- change here
$("#selects select[name='" + folder_id + "']").after('<span>Hi></span>');
//         also note the `>` you probably don't want here ----^
```

[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYzvL/8/)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine but your folder_id was wrong so it didn't match.

fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/yYzvL/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var folder_id = "folder_id";

$("#selects select[name='" + folder_id + "']").append('<span>Hi</span>');
```

Your id was set incorrectly, plus some HTML was incorrect in the span being appended.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to everyone else's answers, which are correct, why are you adding a `<span>` to a `<select>` list?

Surely you should be adding something like this if you're trying to add a new option?

```
$("#selects select[name='" + folder_id + "']").append('<option>Hi</option>');
```

This will add a new option to the select list, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/yYzvL/1/) fiddle.

---

Alternatively, if you're trying to add the text to the option list, why not something like this?

```
$("#selects select[name='" + folder_id + "'] option").append('<span>Hi</span>');
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yYzvL/9/) fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

See my updated (working) example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yYzvL/6/

There were several issues with your code:

1 - Incorrect value assigned to `folder_id`
2 - Not using `<option>` tag for value you are appending

The updated JavaScript is:

```
var folder_id = "folder_id";
$('#selects select[name="' + folder_id + '"]').append($('<option>Hi</option>'));
```